# Using vector elements as for index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I made this small meaningless example for you to see my problem:

```
function a = prova ()
    n=5;
    i = zeros(n,1);
    for i(1) = 1:n %Here is the problem, neither i{1} would work
        disp('hello world');
    end
    a=4;
end
```

Matlab does not like me using i(1) as my index for the 'for' loop:

```
Error: File: prova.m Line: 4 Column: 6
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or
bracket.
```

If I replace i(1) with j, everything works fine.
Is not possible to use an array cell to store the indexes of different loops?

I have to do something like:

```
...
for i5 = 1 : nChannel
    for i6 = 1 : nChannel
    for i7 = 1 : nChannel
        for i8 = 1 : nChannel
        for i9 = 1 : nChannel
            for i10 = 1 : nChannel
            A = aFunction(para, true, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10);
end %all fors
```

And i wanted to replace it with:

```
...
for i(5) = 1 : nChannel
    for i(6) = 1 : nChannel
    for i(7) = 1 : nChannel
        for i(8) = 1 : nChannel
        for i(9) = 1 : nChannel
            for i(10) = 1 : nChannel
            A = aFunction(para, true, i_count, i);
end %all fors
```

At the moment this is my workaround:

```
for i5 = 1 : nChannel
i(5)=i5;
for i6 = 1 : nChannel
    i(6)=i6;
        for i7 = 1 : nChannel
        i(7)=i7;
            for i8 = 1 : nChannel
            i(8)=i8;
```

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: i have some nested for and within them I call another function, to who i have to pass the actual indexes of that iteration. I'd have used this to just pass the vector i instead of the single i1, i2, i3...

Comment: I don't quite get your idea. Can you share more code?

Comment: for i5 = 1 : nChannel

        for i6 = 1 : nChannel
     for i7 = 1 : nChannel
         for i8 = 1 : nChannel
      for i9 = 1 : nChannel
          for i10 = 1 : nChannel
   A = aFunction(para, true, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10);

Comment: You can post these code in your answer. It will be more clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I have done it

Answer (score 0):

`i` is the index variable of the loop (in each iteration `i` gets a value from `1:n` sequentially. Setting this variable to `j` (or any variable name) will assign a single value it it per iteration.

`i(1)` is the value 0 in your example, so it's like saying `0=1`.

Just use `stored_val = i` inside the loop to get the current value. In a nested process, each outer-loop variable exists in all the inner-ones. So, inside the inner-most loop do 
`i_all = [i1, i2, i3]` and pass this as input to the function.

Also, avoid the use of `i` and `j` as any type of variable in MATLAB (See: [Using i and j as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab))